# how to return equivalent Arrays

Tags: java

A function  named equivalentArrays that has two array arguments and returns 1 if the two arrays contain the same values (but not necessarily in the same order), otherwise it returns 0. Note that the arrays do not have to have the same number of elements, they just have to have one of more copies of the same values.

```
public class Equavalenarray {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

            int  result= equivalentArrays(new int[] {}, new int[]  {});
            System.out.println(result);     

            result=equivalentArrays (new int [] {0,2,1,2}, new int [] {0,2,1,2,1});
            System.out.println(result);
            result=equivalentArrays (new int [] {3,1,2,0}, new int [] {0,2,1,0});
            System.out.println(result);

    }

    public static int equivalentArrays(int[ ] a1, int[ ] a2) {
        if(a1==null || a2==null) return 0;

        for(int i=0; i<a1.length; i++) {
            for(int j=0; j<a2.length; j++) {
                if(a1[i]==a2[j] ) 
                {
                return 1;               
                }
        }


    }
        return 0;

}
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: "do not have to have the same number of elements". Than how can they be considered equivalent? Are you saying that this { 1, 2, 3, 3 } is equivalent to { 1, 2, 3 } ?

Comment: The code returns 1 (meaning both arrays have same value) before the whole array has been scanned.

Comment: It doesn't matter what the size of length of the array(size of the array may differ but the values inside array is same), if the values in both array are same return 1, unless if one of the values is not present in the other array it returns 0.

Comment: Both the title and body of your Question are unclear. The title should summarize your *specific* technical issue, what makes your Question unique amongst the millions of Questions posted on Stack Overflow. And your prose in the body should explain the situation and goal more clearly. Also mention if this is school homework or real work. And the example code should indicate expected results, what defines success or failure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class Equavalenarray {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
            System.out.println(equivalentArrays(new int[]{0,1,2}, new int[]{2,0,1}));
            System.out.println(equivalentArrays(new int[]{0,1,2,1}, new int[]{2,0,1}));
            System.out.println(equivalentArrays( new int[]{2,0,1}, new int[]{0,1,2,1}));
            System.out.println(equivalentArrays( new int[]{0,5,5,5,1,2,1}, new int[]{5,2,0,1}));
            System.out.println(equivalentArrays( new int[]{5,2,0,1}, new int[]{0,5,5,5,1,2,1}));
            System.out.println(equivalentArrays( new int[]{0,2,1,2}, new int[]{3,1,2,0}));
            System.out.println(equivalentArrays( new int[]{3,1,2,0}, new int[]{0,2,1,2}));
            System.out.println(equivalentArrays( new int[]{1,1,1,1,1,1}, new int[]{1,1,1,1,1,2}));
            System.out.println(equivalentArrays( new int[]{ }, new int[]{3,1,1,1,1,2}));
            System.out.println(equivalentArrays( new int[]{ }, new int[]{ }));

        }

        public static int equivalentArrays(int[] a1, int[] a2) {
            if(a1==null && a2==null) return 0;
            boolean found;

            for(int i : a1) {
                found = false;
                for(int j : a2) {
                    if(i==j) {
                        found = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }

                if(found==false) {
                    return 0;
                }
            }

            for(int i : a2) {
                found = false;
                for(int j : a1) {
                    if(i==j) {
                        found = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }

                if(found==false) {
                    return 0;
                }
            }
            return 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there with your function. To finish, we'll need to do some workarounds here.

You can check each value within the smaller array and remove the compared value in the bigger array (in case of repeated values).
if in some comparison they're different, it returns 0. If it reach the end of smaller array, they are equals.

Replace your for loops by this snippet:

```
// converted the values to ArrayList to remove values easily.
// PS: to convert them to ArrayList, the array types must of the Integer
List<Integer> l1 = new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(a1.length <= a2.length ? a1 : a2)); // to save in l1 the smaller array
List<Integer> l2 = new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(a2.length >= a1.length ? a2 : a1)); // to save in l2 the bigger array

for(int i=0; i<l1.size(); i++) {
    if(!l2.contains(l1.get(i)))
        return 0;
    else
        l2.remove(l2.indexOf(l1.get(i)));
}
return 1;
```

Updated live example [here](https://onlinegdb.com/r1eyYDfMwV).

Comment: Checking the length is redundant. The `Arrays.equals` call  checks that.

Comment: This Answer does not address the Question, which seems to be about distinct values.

Comment: Perform some test with this method, cause if arrays have different lenght, but the minor one are contained in the major one, eg: `{1, 2, 3, 4}` and `{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}` it will return `true`.

Comment: In your case you are right, what am I thinking is in this way It doesn't matter what the size of length of the array(size of the array may differ but the values inside array is same), if the values in both arrays are same return 1, unless if one of the values is not present in the other array it returns 0.